# Bootstrap grid formatting column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This might be a simple question for someone with good bootstrap knowledge but I am stumped.

I have a "search bar" which is an input and a button at the top of my page and then a row with 4-col blocks below so I end up with a search bar that spans the full width of the top and then the div's with some content form 3 columns.

My issue is that the search bar at the top is a bit wider than the three 4-col blocks. Does anyone know how to restrict the search bar to be only as wide as the three div blocks in a responsive way? I tried just changing width but that only works at the larger media size. I need a bootstrap solution.

this isn't the exact implementation because it is actually a react project and some content is generated dynamically but its a bootstrap problem so I'm leaving out the react stuff.

Here is mode code:

```
 <div class="fluid-container">
    <div class="row flex-xl-nowrap">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-9 py-md-3 pl-md-5 bd-content" role="main">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="input-group mb-3">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                 <div class="input-group-append">
                   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               * some content *
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
               * some content *
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
               * some content *
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

any suggestions welcome

[image]

Comment: which exact version of bootstrap are you using? I tried your code with v4 and I don't see the space. Could you add some pictures of what your issue is?

Comment: it's 4.1.3. Let me add a picture

Comment: Your bootstrap code is correct, and if your first row grows more, the other rows will grow as well, so this is not the problem. Those spaces at the right of the inputs look like the inputs are not filling the complete divs with the `col-md-4` classes. The best way to see this is to see the complete generated html code with these inputs, or try looking in the developer console (F12 in all browsers) and see if there is actually a space that you don't want.

Comment: Yes I was using dev tools. But that did make me think of something and it checked the generated code and the width of those are set to 90%... which explains why the search bar is wider. Sorry, I feel stupid now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your `* some content *` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your outermost div you have used the class="fluid-container" when you really meant to have the bootstrap class="container-fluid" this may be causing some issues since your rows should be in container classes. You may also find it useful to wrap both the search bar and your three columns in the same div with class="container-fluid" or class="container" to get them to be the same width.

Comment: Thanks Lauren! But I solved the issue. It was that one of the react components was set to 90% width instead of 100%, so over three of them they did not take up the full width as expected.